# Using Link inside asp.net MVC4 PartialView to call and pass parameters to an action method and render another PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Within a study course project, I have an MVC PartialView called `_item`, and inside it I put an      `href` link (`<a href = '@Url.Action("AddToShoppingCard", "Home", Model)'>`) to call and pass parameters to an Action method (AddToShopingcart) in the Home controller which in turn renders another PartialView (_Footer) in the main `_layout`. 
Although I could do that, but the problem is that when I click the ActionLink, it throws me outside the main `_layout` and displays only the `_Footer` content in the browser.

Comment: Try calling `@Html.Partial("_Footer", yourModel)` from your _layout view

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AJAX link instead:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Add to shopping cart", 
    "AddToShoppingCard", 
    "Home", 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "someDivYouWantToUpdateWithThePartial" 
    }
)
```

The Ajax.ActionLink helper will generate a normal `<a>` tag with the exception that it will add some HTML5 data-* attributes to it that are interpreted by the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script (that you need to include to your page) and which will AJAXify this anchor. The AjaxOptions allow you to specify some properties of the AJAX request such as for example the id of some DOM element that you want to be updated when the AJAX request succeeds. In your case that could be some div that will receive the PartialView returned by the controller action that is being invoked with AJAX. This way only a portion of the page will be refreshed and the browser will not navigate away from it.